# Redirecting to own controller methods

Tags: laravel

**Signup controller**:

```
<?php
    class Signup extends BaseController
    {
        public function getNew()
        {
            return Redirect::action('Signup@success');
        }

        public function success()
        {
            echo "successful";
        }
    }
?>
```

**Routes.php**

```
Route::controller('signup', 'Signup');
```

So when I go to `localhost/signup/new` it should throw out **successful** but ends with `Unknown action [Signup@success].` error.

I read many same topics before but didn't help me at this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use a certain format.. see **[RESTful Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers)**

it says "Next, just add methods to your controller, *prefixed with the HTTP verb they respond to*"

change your **Signup controller** to:

```
<?php
    class Signup extends BaseController
    {
        public function getNew()
        {
            return Redirect::action('Signup@getSuccess');
        }

        public function getSuccess()
        {
            echo "successful";
        }
    }
?>
```

and everything should work now..

Comment: Tnx. Do you mean RESTful controllers in fact?

Comment: ahh yes.. sorry for that. updated my answer.. wrong link copied. ;)